# Pull friends uid using fb_graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth

does anyone know how to pull a list of facebook friends uid using fb_graph? My current code is below but it does not work. I'm using devise and omniauth.

In my user controller

```
def profile
  profile ||= FbGraph::User.me(self.authentications.find_by_provider('facebook').token).fetch
end
```

In my view

```
<% current_user.profile.friends.each do |friend| %>
<%= friend.uid %>
<% end %>
```

I've been looking for solution for days but still in vain and will appreciate if anyone could tell me the clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `friend.identifier` instead of `friend.uid`.